# Can I Use Strapi (Headless CMS) for user management?

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I want to use Strapi.io for my react project which will basically have a login system. And all user can only view and display thier created data?

Comment: Nice question, but descript more and show some codes to have better post quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be handled that way yes, but you will need to write some policies for users to only view their own (as well as create/update/delete) information. Typically this is called an isOwner policy that can be done via policies or by overriding the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You have complete control of everything. You decide what a user sees whether authenticated or not....